# Add class to accordion heading using AngularJS ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want use `ng-class` to conditionally add a class to the `accordion-heading`, but it appears that not even setting a class explicitly on the element gets preserved. I have this:

```
<div accordion close-others="true">
    <div ng-repeat="currItem in items" accordion-group>
        <div accordion-heading class="myClass">My Heading {{$index}}</div>
        <div class="accordion-inner myClass">asdf asdf asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmhx5/1/

When I inspect the accordion heading element, the class `myClass` is nowhere to be found. Is there some reason I can't add classes to the accordion heading?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the CSS inside the directive `accordion-heading` tags:

```
<accordion-heading>
    <div class="myClass">My Heading {{$index}}</div>
</accordion-heading>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the class I'm adding is to set a gray-ish background color on the heading to give it a disabled-type look. If I do it on an element inside the `accordion-heading` it's not setting the background color for the whole heading, and doesn't look good. See http://jsfiddle.net/Zmhx5/3/

Answer (score 1):

In Angular UI Bootstrap, they have created a directive for `accordion-heading`. Template for this is written in `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. Try to modify directive for `accordion-heading`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue trying to conditionally apply a background color to the heading with `ng-class`. This is a bit of a workaround, but it does the trick.

First we need to remove the padding from the heading. If you inspect it, you'll see that it generates a `div` with a `.panel-heading` class and a `padding: 10px 15px` (see note below). The padding is what causes issues when trying to apply a background to a nested `div`, so lets remove it.

```
.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now we can add our nested `div` and give it the same padding to get back our previous look.

```
<accordion-heading>
    <div class="myClass" style="padding: 10px 15px">My Heading {{$index}}  </div>
</accordion-heading>
```

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zmhx5/25/)

**Note my code above is from a different version of ui-bootstrap. The classes were slightly different in this jsfiddle, so you will see a slightly different solution. The concept, however, is the same.**

Answer (score 0):

you could just apply your CSS to an outer div like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div accordion close-others="true">
        <div class="myClass" ng-repeat="currItem in items" accordion-group>
            <div accordion-heading>
                <div>My Heading {{$index}}</div>

            </div>

            <div class="accordion-inner">asdf asdf asdf</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
}

.accordion-inner {
    background-color: green;
    color: black; 
}
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
});
```

then, change it to use ng-class and it should work just fine

pd: (Sorry about the bad english)